# NameError: member not defined with discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

The purpose of the command is to add a point (coin) to the *mentioned* user (and add them in the database if they aren't already in it), but I get the NameError: name 'member' is not defined.

```
@client.command()
async def gift(ctx,*, member : discord.Member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, member.id)
        await add_coin(users, member.id, 1)

        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            users = json.dump(f)

async def update_data(users, user):
    if not member.id in users:
        users[member.id] = {}
        users[member.id]['coins'] = 0

async def add_coin(users, user, coin):
    users[member.id]['coins'] += coin
    await ctx.send(f'{member.id} has {coin} coins')
```

The traceback:

```
Ignoring exception in command gift:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kiaza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 79, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kiaza\Documents\discord bot\bot.py", line 57, in gift
    await update_data(users, member.id)
  File "C:\Users\Kiaza\Documents\discord bot\bot.py", line 64, in update_data
    if not member.id in users:
NameError: name 'member' is not defined

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kiaza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 863, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Kiaza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 728, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kiaza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\
discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 88, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'member' is not defined
```

Comment: Hi, can you send the full traceback, like the line where it happens?

Comment: traceback added. @Gugu72

Comment: Looks like in update_data and add_coin you are calling a "member" object, but the arguments for the function don't include a member object or anything of a sort. Change all the "member.id" to "user.id".

Comment: Did that. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `member` equal to the module, `discord.member`, in the command definition.
If you're attempting to use a converter, you need to use a type hint and refer to the [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) class.
See [the documentation for Discord converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters) for more information and examples.

Comment: I replaced the converter part and fixed the typo with `discord.Member`, but now I am getting the NameError where the name "member" is not defined.

Comment: You need to define `member`. It's impossible to tell you more without the relevant code and full traceback.

Comment: Can you now edit your question with the updated code?

Comment: This is a separate question now. You should make new questions instead of editing them for additional questions after your original question was already answered. As I said, you need to define `member`. Your parameter names for `update_data` and `add_coin` are `user` rather than `member`. See [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names) for further information on scope.

Answer (score 0):

In the `gift` function, you're calling `update_data` and `add_coin` with `member.id` as the `user` argument.

In these 2 functions, just replace all the `member.id` by `user`, which is equal to the member id.